# WordPress Multisite: Problema para acessar painel de site secundário

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Fiz uma instalação de um site usando WordPress usando o recurso de multsite. A instalação foi ok seguindo todas as instruções, porém todos os dias a URL de um site muda direto no banco de dados, e isso dificulta o acesso ao painel deste site.

A impressão que tenho é que há alguma configuração que sempre atualiza no período da noite o campo "siteurl" deste site com o domínio (sem o path do diretório). Alguém tem alguma idéia de como resolver isso?

O site secundário está em dominio.com.br/english. O conteúdo funciona normalmente, o problema está apenas no acesso ao painel do site secundário que insiste em voltar a configuração para o endereço raiz dominio.com.br/wp-admin ao invés de dominio.com.br/english/wp-admin.

Obrigado.

Comment: Muito estranho esse sintoma... tentou desligar todos os plugins? ou pelo menos a maioria deles. Pode tentar analizar o jobs cron com este plugin [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/)

Answer (score 1):

### Revise as seguintes etapas:

1- Adicione o seguinte código ao seu arquivo `wp-config.php` em `/var/www/html/` acima da linha: /* Isto é tudo, pare de editar! Divirta-se publicando. */:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'dominio.com.br');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

2- Adicione o seguinte no seu arquivo `.htaccess` em `/var/www/html/`, substituindo outras regras do WordPress:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

3- Se estiver tudo correto e ainda não tenha funcionado, adicione os seguintes códigos ao seu arquivo `wp-config.php` em `/var/www/html/`

```
define('WP_HOME','http://dominio.com.br');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://dominio.com.br');
```

Fontes: [Ativando Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Ativando_o_Multisite), [Mudando URL do Site Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Mudando_o_URL_do_Site)